# Custom Mouse Up/Down View Modifier Prevents View Hierarchy from Updating

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a custom view modifier to detect mouse up/down events within a SwiftUI view hierarchy. This is my solution so far:

```swift
extension View {

    func onMouseDown(action: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> some View {
        MouseDownView(action: action) { self }
    }

}

struct MouseDownView<Content: View>: View {

    let action: (Bool) -> Void

    let content: () -> Content

    init(action: @escaping (Bool) -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.action = action
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        MouseDownRepresentable(action: action, content: content())
    }

}

struct MouseDownRepresentable<Content: View>: NSViewRepresentable {

    let action: (Bool) -> Void

    let content: Content

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSHostingView<Content> {
        MouseDownHostingView(action: action, rootView: content)
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: NSHostingView<Content>, context: Context) {

    }

}

class MouseDownHostingView<Content: View>: NSHostingView<Content> {

    let action: (Bool) -> Void

    init(action: @escaping (Bool) -> Void, rootView: Content) {
        self.action = action

        super.init(rootView: rootView)
    }

    required init(rootView: Content) {
        fatalError()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        action(true)
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        action(false)
    }

}
```

It works, in the sense that the closure passed to `onMouseDown` is getting called whenever a mouse up/down event occurs within the the view that it was applied to (even taking non-rectangular shapes into account). Unfortunately though, there is an issue that prevents the view from updating when any of its `@State` variables get modified inside the passed closure.

Example usage:

```swift
struct PlayerView<Content: View>: View {

    private let content: () -> Content

    @State var isPlaying = true

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content()

            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)

                Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "play.fill" : "pause.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
            }
            .onMouseDown { isDown in
                if isDown {
                    // ...
                } else {
                    isPlaying.toggle()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
        }
    }

}
```

`isPlaying` gets toggled everytime the circular view is clicked, but the image never updates. How can this be? Does this configuration of an `NSViewRepresentable` inside of an `NSHostingView` somehow mean, that the modified view is no longer formally part of the original view hierarchy, and therefore not allowed to update it?

I tried wrapping `isPlaying` as a published property inside of an `ObservableObject` that gets attached to the view as a `@StateObject`, but it showed the same behavior.

Does anyone know what's going on here and/or how to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SwiftUI does not see dependency through NSView bridge anymore, so instead the content should remain in SwiftUI world, but modifier/handler be placed above it, like

```
extension View {
    func onMouseDown(action: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.overlay(
            MouseDownView(action: action) { 
               Color.clear.contentShape(Rectangle()) 
            })
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.5

Comment: How could the `contentShape` parameter be derived directly from the view that is being modified? Your code allows for registering all clicks within the frame of the view, not just within the circle. I would like to avoid that if possible.